# Can you solve this? Answer isn't 19 or 26

Tags: mathematics, visual

I've found this viral image online, can you solve it? It is tricky, but simpler than you think.

[image: People are losing their shit over this viral riddle! 45, 23, 10, ??; Can you solve that? Answer isn't 19 or 26]

<sup>Source: Originally found it at [CBP - Brain Centers](https://www.facebook.com/brainperformancecenters) Facebook Page.</sup>

Comment: I think that this kind of puzzles are between the most stupid and annoying you can find on the net (usually posted on Facebook with posts like "Only a genius can solve it!"). But, I don't know why, people continues to post and answer them... bah.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My best guess is

> 38

but it requires a lot of assumptions.

The first line is

> 15+15+15=45

The second is

> 4+4+15=23

The third is

> 4+3+3=10

The trick is

> None of the symbols in the 4th are present in the previous three lines, there are 3 bananas in the bunch instead of 4, the clock points to 2 rather than 3, and the geometric shape is missing the square.
>  The square has 4 points, leaving 11 points of the 15, the rest of the numbers can be assumed to be adjusted as they are pointed to as well, making the final equation 2+3+3*11=38

Answer (score 11):

Well, *obviously*, the answer is

> $\approx 40.6556$

From the first equation...

> The value of the shapes inside shapes is the total area of each shape, added together. Since a square, a pentagon, and a hexagon added together is 15 (45/3), and each polygon appears to have the same length edge (lets call it $L$), we can use the formulas for the area of regular polygons to find $L$:
>
>  $ A = \frac{L^2 n}{4 \tan(\frac{180}{n})} $
>
>  Adding the three shapes together, we get
>  $ 15 = \frac{4 L^2}{4 \tan(\frac{180}{4})} + \frac{5 L^2}{4 \tan(\frac{180}{5})} + \frac{6 L^2}{4 \tan(\frac{180}{6})}$
>
>  Solving for L, we get $L \approx 1.6794$
>  We'll need this value in the final line.

For the second equation, it's clear that...

> Each banana is another exponent to the number. Each cluster of 4 bananas is worth 4 (23-15), so we need to find n such that:
>  $ n^{n^{n^n}} = 4$
>
>  Solving this, we find that $n \approx 1.6203$

Now for the third equation...

> Each clock is worth 3. To get this from the time on the clock, you simply add the numbers the hands are pointing to and divide by 5.

Combining this all in the final equation:

> A clock with its hands at 12 and 2 evaluates to 2.8 (from 14/5)
>  A cluster of 3 bananas is $1.6203^{1.6203^{1.6203}}$, which is about 2.8722.
>  The areas of just a hexagon and a pentagon, with side lengths 1.6794, combine to a total area of 12.1800
>
>  With these values, the final answer is:
>  $ 2.8 + 2.8722 + (2.8722 * 12.18) $
>  Which simplifies to $40.6556$

Thanks for the challenge, this was a fun puzzle ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think it's

> 38

Because

> every banana, every hour and every angle of a polygon represents one. Then it's just basic arithmetics.

Answer (score 3):

Answer:

> 2+3+3*11 = 2+3+33 = **38**

because:

> 1 for each hour on the clock, each banana and each "side" of the shape.

Answer (score 2):

Answer

> 38

Reasoning

> You have to pay attention to the graphic icons.  Each icon tells you precisely its value. More of a visual trick leading you on with first three lines so that you think you understand the value of the icons, but in the last line they modify the icons to change the value they represent.  You also need to see the tricky little "x". Beep...

Comment: Please check [all](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/56751/30903) [the](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/56756/30903) [other](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/56752/30903) [answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/56753/30903) before posting another one.

Comment: Also, please make the unspoilered content relevant to what's in the spoilers and in the question.

Comment: Gotcha bobo, sorry, noob here ;)  Quack

Answer (score 1):

> The answer is 38. Notice the number of bananas, polygon sides and the time.
>  [image]

Comment: Please check [all](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/56751/30903) [other](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/56752/30903) [answers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/56753/30903) before posting another one.

Comment: @boboquack, all other answers have very "useful" spoiler.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: @boboquack, I mean why do you think people hide their answers? what is the use of that?

Comment: The point of hiding an answer is so that someone who scrolls down but doesn't want a hint won't see it. Since you've already come to the answer, nothing hurts to check the other answers to see whether you've got a different answer to someone else and you're adding new things - otherwise we would get hundreds of identical answers on every question. You've put spoilers on your answer, so obviously you see some value in doing it.

Comment: @boboquack, you can never find two identical answers,some are just a number and others may have the same answer but with drawings, explanations and so on. Therefore I just post my answer and see how it will be judged and accepted. And by the way, when you see the first correct answer then you can stop reading another "hundreds of identical answers".

Answer (score 1):

An answer to this is

> 35

First line:

> Each cluster of polyhedrons is 15
>  15 + 15 + 15 = 45

Second line:

> Banana = 1
>  4 + 4 + 15 = 23

Third line:

> Each clock is 90° ie 3
>  4 + 3 + 3 = 10

Last line:

> Clock is in 60° ie 2
>  2 + 3 + 3 x 10 = 5 + 30 = 35

Answer (score 1):

My answer is:

> 35

reason 1:

> [image] = 15 (3 shapes)

2:

> [image] = 4 (4 banana)

3:

> [image] = 3 (3 0'clock)

4:

> [image] = 2 (2 o'clock)

5:

> [image] = 3 (3 banana)

6:

> [image] = 10 (2 shapes)

so

> [image]